# What is the difference between Windows UEFI bootmgfw.efi and Windows UEFI bkpbootx64.efi?

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, windows-8

Also help me by explaining why windows UEFI loader was first taking me to windows but now is redirecting back to this page:

[image]

Comment: Wow. Look at all the HP junk on there....

Comment: This question has nothing to do with Ubuntu, you should ask at http://superuser.com/

Comment: Usually nothing. The bkpbootx64.efi is a backup created by Boot-Repair. With Windows the bootmgfw.efi is just really a copy of Windows bootmgfw.efi. But Boot-Repair with its 'Use the standard EFI file` in advanced options creates the bkpbootx64.efi and makes bootx64.efi a copy of shimx64.efi so fallback or hard drive boot entry in UEFI really boots grub not Windows. About the only way to tell which is which is by checking file size or what actually boots. If Boot-Repair created 25_custom for all the HP entries you probably can delete most or all of them.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Usually nothing.

The bkpbootx64.efi is a backup regularly created by Boot-Repair. With Windows the bootx64.efi is just really a copy of Windows bootmgfw.efi. And bootx64.efi is a fallback or hard drive boot entry in UEFI.

But Boot-Repair with its 'Use the standard EFI file` in advanced options creates the bkpbootx64.efi and makes bootx64.efi a copy of shimx64.efi so fallback or hard drive boot entry in UEFI really boots grub not Windows.

About the only way to tell which is which is by checking file size or what actually boots. If Boot-Repair created 25_custom for all the HP entries you probably can delete most or all of them.

Edit 25_custom entries created by Boot-Repair:

```
sudo cp -a /etc/grub.d/25_custom /etc/grub.d/bkp25_custom
```

turn off execute bit or it will run backup also

```
sudo chmod a-x /etc/grub.d/bkp25_custom
sudo nano /etc/grub.d/25_custom
```

Then do:

```
sudo update-grub
```