# Ubuntu is not appearing in the Boot Menu(BIOS) and also the GRUB menu also not appering

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, uefi

I have windows 10 preinstalled on mine laptop. I love both ubuntu and windows so I planned to make DUAL boot my laptop. Then I have installed Ubuntu as 2nd OS to my LP. Everything was successful and I had configured the GRUB(Basics like time out and Default). Then I have to restart my computer and GRUB menu appears and I choose to use Ubuntu.

After my work finished in Ubuntu, I wished to use Windows so I had restart my laptop and GRUB menu appears and chose Window. Suddenly I realized that I forgot some file to bring to Windows so that I wanted to go back to Ubuntu so again restated Laptop. After the restart, I came to know that there is no GRUB menu so that I tried to load using BIOS but I did not found Ubuntu there also.

> Both the OS has booted using UEFI(Secure boot off).
>
> I have checked that the Ubuntu folder is there is the EFI folder(Checked through windows command prompt).
>
> Also made the GRUB as default
>
> I have Ubuntu partition also.

Comment: is fast boot turned off in windows?

Comment: Are you talking about the Secure boot? If yes then I have turned it off

Comment: No, two different things. One is a UEFI feature, the other - fast boot - is a Windows thing.

Comment: I am not sure, can You please guide me to check that?

Answer (score 0):

Are you having the same problem as described here? [Windows 10 changes UEFI boot order every time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/838780/windows-10-changes-uefi-boot-order-every-time)

It looks like your Grub boot option is overridden by Windows. You can still bring back the grub if you bring up the EFI boot selection. Or you can follow the `bcdedit` command to have grub default permanently.

Comment: I have already used bcdedit command. How to bring up the EFI boot selection?

Comment: That's the motherboard feature. Normally it's F12 on bootup logo screen.

Comment: Actually, this is the problem. Now I can't able to see the Ubuntu in the boot menu(In the BIOS). So, can you please say me, How can I bring that?