# How to leave Windows 10 and get back to Ubuntu?

Tags: dual-boot, windows-10

After visiting the original Windows 10 on my dual boot laptop after several months, I'm not able to get back into Ubuntu.

I already have Fastboot disabled, and no `Shift` + Click shutdown or running a shutdown command from the command line won't help me.

It always boots back to Windows.

Comment: I am voting to close this question as a duplicate of [Windows 10 changes UEFI boot order every time](https://askubuntu.com/questions/838780/windows-10-changes-uefi-boot-order-every-time) that you have linked in your answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Can't boot into Ubuntu in Windows 10 / Ubuntu dual boot](https://askubuntu.com/questions/708247/cant-boot-into-ubuntu-in-windows-10-ubuntu-dual-boot)

Answer (score 0):

The issue was, that when Windows was loaded (or maybe updated) it switched around the boot order in the UEFI settings.

For a one-time solution, I was able to go follow this guide
[How to enter UEFI (BIOS) on Windows 10 PCs | Windows Central](https://www.windowscentral.com/how-enter-uefi-bios-windows-10-pcs)
to get to UEFI:

*in windows 10*
**Settings** > **Update & Security** > **Recovery** > **Advanced Startup** > **Restart now**

*on blue screens:*
**Troubleshoot** > **Advanced options** > **UEFI Firmware Settings** > **Restart**

This got me to a UEFI menu where I could find out the boot order was switched to:

1. Windows boot manager
2. ubuntu

Swapping them around, saving and restarting got me back to where I could select Ubuntu.

For a more permanent solution this answer goes into more detail:
[Windows 10 changes UEFI boot order every time - Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/838780/windows-10-changes-uefi-boot-order-every-time)