# Can't boot into ubuntu after resizing partitions

Tags: boot, dual-boot, partitioning

Originally, my Ubuntu partition was ~600 GB and after resizing it to ~182 it worked fine for an evening but now I am no longer able to boot into it.

The boot screen automatically takes me to the Windows install instead of the ubuntu screen with ubuntu as the primary option & a 5 second delay before automatically continuing to boot into ubuntu. I'm not knowledgeable on partitioning as far as what the boot process looks like, what needs to be together, etc... I think a boot partition may have been removed sommehow? I remember two very small partitions and now there is only one.

[image: Picture of Windows Disk Management]

In this picture, from left to right are what I think is 512 MB for the windows boot partition, 180 GB for windows, 180 GB for Ubuntu, 142 GB unallocated, 400 GB for storage/access from both OS's, and 15.9 GB that I also don't know what it does, but I think it's the Linux swap.

I think when I resized / moved things I may have separated my Ubuntu partition from something important? That or after resizing I somehow deleted an important partition for booting into Ubuntu... would appreciate any help! I already did some googling and reading, but didn't find any solid answers... I likely will boot into Ubuntu with a USB and use GParted to also try to view what's going on, and maybe just reinstall Ubuntu...?

Edit after using Boot-repair:

Currently, my ability to boot into Ubuntu and Windows has been fixed, though there are many more options for booting into Windows in the GRUB screen, and only one of them really works... the pastebin is here http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/4YygHynjrc/

Comment: Welcome to [ubuntu.se]! What software did you use for partitioning? Have you tried [Boot-Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair)? If Boot-Repair cannot solve your problem automatically, please post the URL it generates!

Comment: Hey! Sorry for the late reply. I used GParted from an ubuntu USB to do the partition resizing / moving. I have not yet tried Boot-Repair since I haven't had access to that computer for a week, but will try tonight! Thanks for the tip!

Comment: I just finished using Boot-Repair, and have not tried restarting yet. Here is the pastebin http://paste.ubuntu.com/p/4YygHynjrc/

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add details. It helps to keep our Q&A style tidy and could also bring more attention since an edited question gets bounced on the homepage.

Comment: Your partitions shown above are not at all similar to those in Boot-Repair summary report. Is that correct link? Reinstalling grub with Boot-Repair moved Ubuntu to first in boot order. You should have been able to do that in UEFI or using efibootmgr. Boot-Repair also adds entries in ESP with .efi to grub menu. They are all in 25_custom. To edit: https://askubuntu.com/questions/778663/what-is-the-difference-between-windows-uefi-bootmgfw-efi-and-windows-uefi-bkpboo/778705#778705

Comment: my partitions shown above are previous to using Boot-Repair, when I could not boot into Ubuntu. The pastebin should be correct... my boot screen is similar to the link you provided, except with a couple less options.